# Не отображаются стили в FireFox новом

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.

Есть [посадочная страница](http://diabet-help.ru/monastyrskij-chaj/), в опере, ie 11, хроме она отображается более-менее единообразно, а в firefox новом стили некоторые падают почему-то. Исчезают, например, такие вещи, как фон у кнопок, или отступы нарушаются. То же самое по спискам и отступам.

Не силен в верстке, потому обращаюсь за помощью к тем, кто давно в этой сфере. Посоветуйте, как починить страницу под фокс.

Answer (score 1):

Страничка идет с ошибкой 404, поэтому могу лишь "пальцем в небо" предположить, что вам нужно некоторые стили, такие, как `box-shadow`, `text-shadow`, `box-sizing` и прочие из css3 нужно дублировать с приставкой `-moz-`, например:

```
-moz-box-shadow:
-moz-text-shadow:
-moz-box-sizing:
```

Comment: Исправил страницу. Например, у кнопок (зеленых) в фоксе исчезают объвления свойств стилей #zakazukr a:hover {...} Как это исправить?